# Loading Android Contacts with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks in a Promise

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript, android-loadermanager, angular2-nativescript

I'm writing an angular 2 service for my **NativeScript** app that retrieves all the user's contacts. My current implementation uses a synchronous `getContentResolver` method like the one used in [nativescript-contacts](https://github.com/firescript/nativescript-contacts/blob/master/index.android.js#L94). The `cursor.getCount` reports over 7k cursors and freezes the app for a total of ~3 seconds. No good.

I'm following this guide, [using-loaders-in-android](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/), and having no luck so far.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
declare let android: any
declare let java: any

import * as application from "application"
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core"

@Injectable()
export class ContactsService
    extends android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager
    implements android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks {

    private contactsLoader: any = new android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks(
        class extends android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks {
            onCreateLoader(id, args) {
                let projection: Array<string> = [
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.CONTACT_ID,
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.LOOKUP_KEY,
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.PHOTO_URI,
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER,
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.DataColumns.MIMETYPE,
                ]
                return new android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader(
                    application.android.foregroundActivity,
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    'data2 IS 2',
                    null,
                    null
                ).loadInBackground()

            }

            onLoadFinished(param0: android.support.v4.content.Loader, param1: java.lang.Object): void {
                global.tnsconsole.dump('onLoadFinished > param0', param0)
                global.tnsconsole.dump('onLoadFinished > param1', param1)
            }

            onLoaderReset(param0: android.support.v4.content.Loader): void {
                global.tnsconsole.dump('onLoaderReset > param0', param0)
            }
        }
    )

    getContactsAsync(): Promise<any> {
        // since the initLoader method is part of android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager
        this.initLoader(1, null, this)
        // but i get this error :(
        // EXCEPTION: Error: Cannot convert object to Landroid/support/v4/app/LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks; at index 2
        return Promise.resolve([])
    }

}
```

> Does anyone know how to properly implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` so I can run the cursor in a background thread?

Thank you!

Comment: If there isn't an async/background implementation of this already, then you have limited options as to what you can do right now. You can write this natively yourself and bring the code in to your app via a 'dummy' plugin that just consumes the code. The core team is working on threads currently according to their recent roadmap, I think they're shooting for the September update. I think it will be similar to workers in JS so should help out with stuff like this, unfortunately it's not ready yet :/

Comment: During development I'm just using it inside an angular 2 service for convenience/livesync. Once it's ready it'll be wrapped in a plugin. But since these are native methods defined in [android-dts-generator/android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.d.ts](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-dts-generator/blob/master/out_original/android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.d.ts) I should be able to impliment this no problem. I'm very excited for the Workers release in September :D Thank you!